# How should I auto update Maven project when a static HTML file is changed in STS

Tags: java, html, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a requirement, where when I run some code a new HTML file say `abc.html` is created and replaces the old `abc.html` in path `src\main\resources\static\abc.html`.

But when I am running this in browser, this newly created `abc.html` is not being updated even after refreshing the browser. Only after doing a Maven update project, I am able to get the newly created `abc.html` in browser.

So is there a way to automatically update static files so that I do not have to do a Maven update or restart the server.

My static `.html` page is present inside `src\main\resources\static\abc.html` path. And I have `spring-boot-devtools` dependency added in my POM file.

`application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

Comment: Assuming you are using thymeleaf this might help you - https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-boot-auto-reload-thymeleaf-templates

Comment: I am using simple .html file but thank you for response

Comment: try livereload then - http://livereload.com/

Comment: Is it open source and will it work if i deploy it in a server? I will check this article. Thanks for sharing.